# Display the file in page when the type of that is not specified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor

When I want to show an image I use something like this:

```
public ActionResult Show(int id) {
  var MyFile = GetFromDB(id);
  return File(MyFile.Data, MyFile.ContentType);
}
```

And in View:

```
<img alt ="" src='@Url.Action("show", new { id = 36 })'/>
```

So assume we have some other types of file like `txt`, `pdf`, ...
And I think to use a general tag to show all kind of files instead of `<img>`. Does any one have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy, because some files need initialization or need additional declarations to specify how they should be presented, but you can try with iframe:

```
<iframe src='@Url.Action("show", new { id = 36 })'></iframe>
```

It will use browser built-in way of presenting documents.